# Can I call dup2 after vfork?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, dup2, vfork

I want to `vfork()` a child process, but have its `stdout` be different than the parent's `stdout`.

The obvious way to achieve this with `fork()` would be to `dup2()` (and `close()` the original file descriptor) in the child after forking.

Let's say I have the file descriptor ready before calling `vfork()` and just need to call these two system calls before calling an `exec*()` function. Am I allowed to do that?

Comment: No. Use posix_spawn. A good posix_spawn implementation (like musl's) should get you both the benefits of vfork and the ability to run pre-exec actions in the child.

Comment: Can you give me an example of using `posix_spawn()` so that  the underlying system call used is `vfork()` and output is redirected?

Comment: Forget that `vfork()` exists.  The rules on its use are stringent and IMO not worth the trouble. You can call one of the `exec*()` functions or one of the exit functions, and that’s it. Check the rules.

Comment: I read the rules, and found no explanation or discussion of them anywhere.

Comment: @PSkocik All the `posix_spawn` does is call `fork` or `vfork` or possibly Linux `clone`. It is not a very special function in its implementation.

Comment: Why do you want to use vfork instead of fork?  If it's for some specific capability of vfork that fork does not share, consider using clone instad.  If you don't need anything that fork doesn't give you, why bother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is probably yes.

Based on Linux manual, A call to vfork() is equivalent to calling clone(2) with flags specified as:

```
        CLONE_VM | CLONE_VFORK | SIGCHLD
```

Note from clone(2):

CLONE_FILES (since Linux 2.0)
              If  CLONE_FILES is set, the calling process and the child process share the same file descriptor table.  Any file descriptor created by the calling process or by the child
              process is also valid in the other process.  Similarly, if one of the processes closes a file descriptor, or changes its associated flags (using the fcntl(2) F_SETFD oper‐
              ation), the other process is also affected.

```
          If  CLONE_FILES  is not set, the child process inherits a copy of all file descriptors opened in the calling process at the time of clone().  (The duplicated file descrip‐
          tors in the child refer to the same open file descriptions (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptors in the calling process.)  Subsequent operations that open or
          close file descriptors, or change file descriptor flags, performed by either the calling process or the child process do not affect the other process.
```

**So after vfork, file operations in child process are isolated by default.**